# Nginx not logging all access in access.log (missing data of redirected requests)

Tags: nginx

In Nginx I have a redirection of all incoming http traffic to the same url but with https.
When I check the access log I only see the 301 error, but not the following petition, that can be a 200 or a 404 or whatever.

**How can I see that information in the logs of Nginx?**

All I want to see is what happen after you get redirected, because the redirection may work but the underlying url may not, and as of now I can only know what works by trying myself (and that doesn't mean that in a moment someone can get another different response because of who knows)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll post a separate answer to this, because I think someone may find it useful.

The problem is not with Nginx or its logging, if you try to access the problematic URL you can see that from a browser the request is properly recorded, that means, it's not recorded when the request is sent from an external application, scanners or whatever software used, that doesn't react the same way as a web browser and that don't follow the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The following requests should be in same access.log file. The only note is that they will not follow each other.

301 response is returned to browser and then it determine follow propose URL or not. And this is not happen imediately. So after initial 301 log record folowing request may be logged after 10, 100 or even 1000 non-related log message. All is depend on trafic and how many logs you have for single page.